# Swift setting variable inline or in function?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios9

What is the Swift standard for setting a variable you already know the value for? Here are the 2 different ways I'm thinking of.

**Option 1: Declaring the variable in the class and then setting it in the `ViewDidLoad` method**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
    var sampleString: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        sampleString = "Hello"
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Declaring the variable in the class and setting it inline**

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    var sampleString = "Hello"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Which is the preferred way to do this in Swift? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's two different times in the life of your controller. Read the UIViewController reference.

Comment: Could `var sampleString` be `let sampleString` (treated as constant)? I would choose the second version. Fewer lines of code makes it easier to maintain etc... Also ensures sampleString will be available before view is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have two fundamentally different types in your two examples.  In the first example, the type is an implicitly unwrapped optional `String` (i.e., `String!`), which means it can accept the `nil` value.  In the second example, it is just `String`.  If the value does not need to be `nil` assignable, the second option is better.

With regard to your actual question.  I would say the second option is preferable, as you initialize the value earlier and there is no chance that you will use it before it is initialized.  This would be equivalently good to declaring the type as `String` and deferring the initialization to an `init` method.

The `viewDidLoad` method is only useful for `UIViewController` instances, and doesn't get invoked until the view is loaded (which typically is during presentation).  Waiting to initialize a value until then is probably not preferred and wouldn't be useful in objects that don't subclass `UIViewController`.